# Oracle Apex "Click here to create a New Session" link empty href

Tags: oracle-apex

Hope you are doing good.

I am facing problem in Session timeout. When idle session timeout, a modal dialog open to create a new session with button Sign in again, but it takes end user to developer login page. When i checked logs, there is empty href for that link as shown in image.[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ictYe.png) .
[Session Time Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bksw.png)

How can i fix this issue.

Apex version 20.2

Thanks

After session timeout when clicks on "Sign in Again" or "Click here to create new session" then user should be redirected to Application Login page instead of Developer Login page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Shared components > Security Attributes > Session management] page? It contains *timeout URLs* you probably didn't set:

[image]

Comment: I am using #LOGOUT_URL# (also tried these &LOGOUT_URL. , &APP_ID. , f?p=100 etc ) but it does not work.
If I refresh page instead of Clicking "here" it works fine to redirect to the application login page.

Comment: Have a look at Jon Dixon's article (https://blog.cloudnueva.com/all-about-apex-timeouts) about *timeouts*; maybe it'll help.

Comment: Yeah i have seen this before.
Just tried again when the session ended URL looks like this (ords/orcl/r/myapp/f?p=115:1:0:IDLE) with page error